# FFMPEG Add Aanother Command

Tags: ffmpeg

thanks to [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan) he has helped by combining 2 commands;

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 5 -t 10 -vf "delogo=x=1075:y=9:w=170:h=52" -c:a copy ouput.mp4`

I'm trying to add one more command into it, which is an image/ logo overlay. 
`(trim > delogo > add watermark)`

`-i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=0:0"`

ive tried a few combinations but just cant get it right, if anyone can help would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -ss 5 -t 10 -filter_complex "[0]delogo=x=1075:y=9:w=170:h=52[v];[v][1]overlay=0:0" -c:a copy ouput.mp4
```

The placement of output `-ss -t` relative to `-vf` or `-filter_complex` doesn't matter. The filtering takes place first.